# How can I get sheet names in a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wonder if someone can tell me how can I change the panel that I obtain with this script and instead getting the names of my sheets in a column of the active sheet. Thanks a lot.

```
function sheetNames() {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
   var  string = "Lista de hojas:\n" ;
for ( var s = 0 ; s < sheets.length ; s++)
{
  string += sheets[s].getName()+ "\n";
}
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(string);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this sample?

```
function sheetNames() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  var  string = "Lista de hojas:\n" ;
  var sn = [[i.getName()] for each (i in sheets)];
  var str = "";
  var strs = [str += i + "\n" for each (i in sn)];
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, sn.length, sn[0].length).setValues(sn);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(string + str);
}
```

This script imports sheet names to column 'A' on the active sheet. And message dialog is opened.

Comment: It was just what I needed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Santiago Díaz-Hellín Sepúlveda Thank you, too. If you push accepted button on this your question, everyone will be able to see this as a solved question. And also I'm glad. If you don't know about "accepted", please check this. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Tanaike That's a pretty neat way to write loops.  Where could I go to learn that.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for your comments. I check ES5 and ES6, I always think whether they can be applied to GAS, because GAS is continued to advance. So I could notice that one liner like this can be applied. I hope that this answer will be useful for you.